# What does "channel emotions" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have found it in this [video](https://youtu.be/r8OTgthhS0g). It is at 53 second. Here is the context:

> Somehow, **channelling this strong emotion** had substantial physiological effects on Hans.

Comment: Have you tried to Google the phrase?  I did so and found several articles explaining. Have a look at these and come back with more detail of any doubts you still have.

Comment: Oxford online : **channel something (into something)** - *to direct money, feelings, ideas, etc. towards a particular thing or purpose.* Example usage. ***He channels his aggression into sport.*** In your *specific* context, it seems that Hans channels his [whatever] into ***rage*** - which is a rather unusual strategy, but don't knock it if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably the cited text reflects muddled thinking and/or careless use of English. Consider a typical ***literal*** use of ***to channel***...

> 1: *We channelled our waste water into the river*

Note that it's *just about* possible to use ***to channel*** (literally *or* figuratively) without specifying what you're channelling something ***into***. So a therapist, for example, might say *You should try to channel your anger* (by implication, into constructive rather than destructive activities).

But in the cited context, Hans is "channelling" his ***pain*** (not an emotion) into ***rage / anger*** (which *is* a "strong emotion"). That would be equivalent to following up my example above by saying...

> 2: *Channelling **the river** like that saved us money on our water company bills*

...which to my mind is complete nonsense. That *should* be expressed as...

> 3: *Channelling **our waste water** [away] like that saved us money on our water company bills*